# LAMP setup with remote MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, lamp

I am new to linux and I want to set up my network with one centralized MySQL server. I want my Web server to have Apache, PHP, and Wordpress installed with all MySQL references pointing to the database server.

I am having a hard time finding documentation on how to configure this. How do I set up a LAMP configuration across two servers with MySql as a stand alone dbms?

How do I congigure Apache, PHP and Wordpress in this setup?

Comment: You wanna have a Mysql on your Server and all clients remote on it?

Comment: yes, MySQL server on one machine and all the other applications running as a database client from another machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna have your mysql on a remote server and let your local applications to connect to it , follow this steps :

- run your mysql on your server (with a specific ip/computer name)
- find `my.conf` in your mysql directory
- edit `my.conf` and find the line : `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`
- comment the line `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` by adding `#` before it
- restart your lamp by running this command  `/opt/lampp/lampp restart`
- in your local application set the mysql host from `localhost` to `server ip` or `server name`

DO NOT Forget before apply any changes create a backup from you my.conf, And grant all access to a user in your mysql on your server.